# Problema para acceder a LocalHost usando XAMPP

Tags: laravel, xampp, dns, localhost, virtualhost

Estoy en este momento iniciando con todo el tema de Apache y Laravel, mi intención es configurar un VirtualHost.

Tengo el error 403:

**Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al directorio solicitado. No existe un documento índice, o el directorio está protegido contra lectura.
Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor comuníqueselo al administrador del portal.**

Antes, LocalHost funcionaba correctamente, pero ahora, me sale ese error.

Lo que hice antes de que me lanzara el error fue lo siguiente:

1) Modificar los permisos del directorio para que cualquiera pueda accederlos.
(El directorio es: C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra)

2) Intenté realizar la configuración de mi Host, no funcionó así que borre el pedazo de código con respecto a la configuración en el archivo httpd-xampp.conf (es decir, en teoría quedo igual)

Les envío como luce el fichero de configuración: 
**httpd-xampp.conf**

```html
#
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php7_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php7_module>
     <Files "status.php">
      php_admin_flag safe_mode off
     </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php7_module>
      <Files "webalizer.php">
       php_admin_flag safe_mode off
      </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Y asi luce el fichero de httpd-vhosts.conf

```html
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>
```

Eso es todo, si necesitan información adicional, se las facilitaré, de igual forma trataré de encontrar las soluciones y si la consigo la compartiré con ustedes